# 2013 Toyota Tundra disable emergency brake alarm

Tags: brakes

When I'm driving through the pastures at my farm early morning or late evening I like to press my emergency brake pedal down for one click and that turns off the running lights but when I go over 5 miles an hour An alarm beeps at me how do I turn that alarm off

Answer (score 4):

If I'm correct, your root problem is that you don't want the daytime running lights to switch on. Your current solution works, because the DRL's switch off when the handbrake is on.

There are two ways to keep the DRL off. One involves cutting a thin grey wire (google it, I'm not going to be responsible for you cutting into your cars wiring!). The other way involves changing the relay out for a different one.

Call your local Toyota Dealer, and ask them for a "Flasher Relay without DRL". Costs just over $50. You need part number 819800C020, which will replace your current part number 819800C010.

To get to the relay, you need to take off the driver door (left) sill panel, the kick panel, and the knee bolster. The flasher is on the left.

Note that if your Toyota has headlights which come on automatically at dusk, you'll probably find that that doesn't work any longer. But they still work manually just fine. That's the only side effect (that I know of) caused by swapping out that relay.

Comment: The third way involves taping a piece of cardboard over your lights for pastor drives.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do it with the Toyota TechStream software and a J2534 device. Check with a dealer. It doesn't appear as a customization option in the owners manual.

You could tap into the daytime running light system. You'd have to interrupt the power from the DRL relay. It looks like the parking brake switch is always grounded. So you setup a relay that uses the parking brake switch as the relay coil ground, power from the DRL relay as terminal 30 and have terminal 87 as output to the headlights. When the parking brake switch is open the relay coil loses ground and thus the DRLs won't have a path to the headlights while retaining DRL otherwise.

As for other exterior lights just turn the switch to off.

Answer (score 0):

The alarm beeps because your vehicle is warning you not to drive with the emergency brake on, and for good reason (excessive brake wear + safety).

If you turn the alarm off you'll lose the alarm in useful situations as well, such as if you leave the brake on when actually driving at speed.

So the *real* solutions are:

- Don't turn the brake on.
- Don't drive over 5mph
- Learn to live with the alarm.

An alternate solution is to find a way to turn the running lights off so you dont have to do this:

- Tape something over the lights but don't forget to remove it on real streets.
- Install a running light switch (you'll have to consult your vehicle's wiring diagrams and do some work), but this risks making your car not street legal. Definitely don't forget to turn them on again on real streets. I do not recommend this.

That said if you want to turn off the alarm you'll just have to find the alarm buzzer and disconnect it. You'll have to consult your service manual and wiring diagram and do a bit of work. In particular if the buzzer is a functional part of a larger circuit you may have to bypass it (possibly adding something with equivalent resistance) rather than disconnect. But check the wiring diagrams, it may even be as simple as pulling a fuse (although I doubt it) or unplugging an easily accessible connector.

Covering your running lights with some cardboard and duct tape probably involves the least amount of work and risk.

Comment: Why would eliminating automatic DRL make a vehicle "not street legal"? I thought lights were only mandatory 30 mins. before dusk until 30 mins. after dawn.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it That depends on where you live (which the OP didn't specify) - some jurisdictions require lights at all times.

Comment: @JimmyFix-It That's why I said "risk" and not definitive. I have no idea what the OPs local laws are or what time the OP usually drives on streets. So it's merely a possibility. Check your local laws. E.g. all of Canada requires DRLs all day except for visitors and vehicles built before 1989, except Nova Scotia, which also requires DRLs or headlights 24/7 for visitors and old vehicles.

Comment: @JasonC Canada requires daytime running lights, but a car without automatic daytime running lights would still be "street legal".  You just have to make sure to turn them on when you are on the road. Case in point: U.S. cars driving in Canada.

Comment: @dan1111 That's true. Well, whatever. I'm not going to change the wording because it's more of a disclaimer since I don't know all the world's laws. It's also gotta pass inspections.